# Submit button state

Tags: jquery-mobile, form-submit

I have a login form which uses jquery and jquerymobile. When I click on Submit button, it changes the state of 'Submit' permanently to selected state. How can I change it back to normal state after button-click.

HTML:

```html
<form id="loginForm">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Please enter your password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```js
$("#loginForm").on("submit", loginForm_submit);
function loginForm_submit() {
  alert("Your password is - " + $("#password", $("#loginForm")).val());
  return false;
}
```

jsFiddle page link: - http://jsfiddle.net/UmeQt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below to your function

```js
$(this).find('.ui-submit').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UmeQt/1/)**

Full code:

```js
$("#loginForm").on("submit", function () {
  $(this).find('.ui-submit').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
  alert("Your password is - " + $("#password", $("#loginForm")).val());
  return false;
});
```